# How can I make this switch statement work? Also how would I get the program to quit out when they enter Q?

Tags: c

How would I get this to work? I get the error code that the letters are not declared, also how do I get the function to quit when they press Q?

```
char getChoice(char* choice)
{
printf("\nEnter the R, P, S, or Q (for quit) ");
scanf("%c", choice);
switch(*choice){
   case R:
   printf("You picked Rock, ");
   break;
   case P:
   printf("You picked Paper, ");
   break;
   case S:
   printf("You picked Scissors, ");
   break;
   case Q:

   default:
   printf("Error: Invalid choice, try again.");
   break; 
   }

 return *choice;
 }
```

Comment: Your `scanf` statement will also read the newline following the input as char, which will lead to an erroneous error message.

Comment: _error code that the letters are not declared_ - it's essential that you understand the difference between an identifier (name of variable, function, etc.) such as `R` and a constant (such as the character constant `'R'` -- notice the single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

1. First put the letters after `case` between `'`.
2. Second: modify que 'Q' case like this:
3. Change `switch(*choice)` to `switch(choice)`. `scanf` wants a pointer and `choice` is already a pointer.

---

```
char getChoice(char* choice)
{
   ...
   case 'Q':
     return 0;
     break;

   default:
     printf("Error: Invalid choice, try again.");
     break;
}
```

Depending on how you call `GetChoice` you might `return` another value than `0`.

There may be more issues depending on how you call `getChoice`.

Comment: well i had it originally without the pointer and i was receiving an error code saying that it wasnt an integer value.

Comment: @JeremyMcMahan edit your question show how you call `getChoice`. This may change a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your case statement like this;

```
switch(*choice)
{
   case 'R':
   printf("You picked Rock, ");
   break;
   case 'P':
   printf("You picked Paper, ");
   break;
   case 'S':
   printf("You picked Scissors, ");
   break;
   case 'Q':

   default:
   printf("Error: Invalid choice, try again.");
   break; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely revamped `get_choice`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // for exit

char get_choice() {
    char choice;
    while (1) {
        printf("\nEnter the R, P, S, or Q (for quit) ");
        if (scanf("%c", &choice) != 1) {
            printf("Error reading a character!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        switch(choice){
        case 'r':
            printf("You picked Rock, ");
            goto exit;
        case 'p':
            printf("You picked Paper, ");
            goto exit;
        case 's':
            printf("You picked Scissors, ");
            goto exit;
        case 'q':
            exit(0);
        default:
            printf("Error: Invalid choice, try again.");
            break;
        }
    }

exit:
    return choice;
}
```

(And `exit` resides in `<stdlib.h>`)

First of all, now you do not need to pass a pointer-to-char to hold the choice; it is done internally to the function. Secondly, we use character constants for the case labels - lowercase, since that's probably what the user would rather write. We loop until a proper value is given; and if given, we jump to the `exit` label with `goto`. We also check the return value of `scanf` and bail out if no characters can be read (end-of-file?)